# Python version output

Tags: python, version

Every time I type "python -v" in cmd or another terminal result same

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffEwv.png)

Comment: type `python -V` capital "V" or `python -VV` for more verbose version output.

Comment: use `python --version`

Answer (score 0):

You must type the v option uppercase `python -V` or with `--version`

Answer (score 0):

According to the --help
-v is verbose mode: It traces all inputs
-V returns version.